Bucatini splits when cooking
Every time I try to cook bucatini pasta it splitting like spaghetti with just a few that stay intact. Water is at a full boil, starts off fine then it splits.tried it several ways and it always ends up the same way. I want the nice thick pasta and I get spaghetti.could it be the pasta? It is Piancone /Roma

What do you mean by it's splitting "like spaghetti"? How much are you cooking the pasta? Could the issue be that you're overcooking the Bucatini to then point it's breaking into pieces?

Do you mean bucatini?

This is unusual.  First, be sure you are cooking to the time on the package. I could see where overcooking might cause this.  If you are cooking properly, this is more likely the sign of a product that is not well made. Try switching brands.
